# Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have two types of strings

```
str1 = "{#decode(en.flower)}"
str2 = "{#en.flower}"
```

I want to capture both of these types of strings by a regular expression, but I can't capture the `str1` string. Capturing the `str2` string is no problem.

My Regular expression is

```
r'\{\#([a-zA-Z]\()?(en|kr)\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\)]?\}'
```

Why can't I capture the `str` string?

Comment: Dont use the expression str=x as it will overwrite the built-in function `str`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\{\#([a-zA-Z]+\()?(en|kr)\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\)]?\}

             ^^
```

You forgot a quantifier.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/12#python

Answer (score 2):

vks's answer has helped you figured out the problem.

This answer can help you enhance your regex pattern for skipping capturing invalid string such as:

```
str1 = "{#decode(en.flower}"
str2 = "{#en.flower)}"
```

In this case you can use `yes-pattern|no-pattern` of python regex:

```
>>> p1 = r'\{\#([a-zA-Z]+\()?(en|kr)\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+[\)]?\}'  # your original pattern
>>> re.match(p1, str1).groups()
('decode(', 'en')
>>> re.match(p1, str2).groups()
(None, 'en')
>>> p2 = r'\{\#([a-zA-Z]+\()?(en|kr)\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+(?(1)\))\}'
>>> print re.match(p2, str1)
None
>>> print re.match(p2, str2)
None
```

`p2` will capture only when `encode(` and `)` exists in pair.